# Why is my Raspberry Pi searching in only pypi simple version?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB RAM variant running latest Raspbian.
Everything works as expected, but when I attempt to pip install something~

```
$pip3 install tensorflow
Searching in indexes pypi.org/simple and piwheels.org/simple
```

And it finds only tf 1.15, which is not what I require.
Could someone tell me what I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pinwheels.org`? Should be `piwheels.org`

Comment: Spell error, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python package repositories (like pypi.org and piwheels.org) tend to provide both a **simple index** (which is used by pip) and a separate browsable HTML index for humans. piwheels.org uses the same structure as pypi.org which provides the simple index at `/simple/` and the human-friendly version at `/project/`.

The `/project/` version is just a website for people to browse and find information about which packages are available. It's never used by pip. Only the simple index is.

By default, pip uses pypi.org/simple as its primary index. Raspbian is configured to add piwheels.org/simple as an additional index. This means that whenever you use pip, it searches pypi.org and then piwheels.org. It finds the "best" file (latest version available with files that will work on your computer with your version of Python), and installs that.

If piwheels has a wheel of the latest version of the package you requested, and it supports your architecture and python version, then pip will choose this file. If it doesn't have the latest verison, but pypi has a source distribution of the latest version, pip will choose this and try to build it from source.

If piwheels doesn't have the latest version, and pypi only has wheels for other architectures (no source), then it will look at the next version and repeat the process until a suitable file is found.

At the time of writing, the latest tensorflow file available on piwheels is version 1.14.0 (you said 1.15 but I think you meant 1.14), and pypi only has wheels (for other platforms), so this is the best file you have available.

The pypi and piwheels project pages provide all the information about which files are available:

- https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/
- https://piwheels.org/project/tensorflow/

You can also use `pip3 -v` to give verbose output to see which files are being chosen and why other files are being discarded.

The alternative is to look at the install pages on tensorflow's website to see if they're hosting an armv7 wheel for a newer version.

Comment: `pip3 install --index-url https://pypi.org/project/ tensorflow` worked for me, so i didnt bother checking the files....
Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

`piwheels/simple` doesn't have anything above TensorFlow 1.9, [link](https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/), where `pypi/simple` has all the updated versions, [link](https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/).

Adding an `--index-url` argument to pip install can let you install from any index.
e.g. with `pypi/simple` for the latest TensorFlow version.

`pip3 install --index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ tensorflow`

More examples on `pip install` can be found in the official [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples).

Comment: Sorry, but apart from the link to the docs, everything in the answer is completely false.